# Entity framework - View 2 Disconnected Entity update

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I have a User entity class:

```
public class User
{
    [Key]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string SecretQuestion { get; set; }
    public string SecretAnswer { get; set; }
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public Nullable<byte> UserType { get; set; }
    public Nullable<bool> Enabled { get; set; }
    public Nullable<DateTime> Created { get; set; }
    public Nullable<DateTime> Modified { get; set; }

    public void LoadWCPModel(UserWCPModel model)
    {
        Username = model.Username;
        Password = model.Password;
        SecretQuestion = model.SecretQuestion;
        SecretAnswer = model.SecretAnswer;
        UserType = model.UserType;
        Enabled = model.Enabled;
    }
}
```

I have a model class for my Web Configuration Portal (WCP):

```
public class UserWCPModel
{
    [Key]
    public int UserId { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Username")]
    [Required]
    public string Username { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    [Required]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Secret question")]
    [Required]
    public string SecretQuestion { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Secret answer")]
    [Required]
    public string SecretAnswer { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "User type")]
    [Required]
    public Nullable<byte> UserType { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Enabled")]
    [Required]
    public Nullable<bool> Enabled { get; set; }

    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public Nullable<DateTime> Created { get; set; }

    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public Nullable<DateTime> Modified { get; set; }

    /// Parameterless constructor for MVC model binder.
    public UserWCPModel()
    {
        Created = DateTime.UtcNow;
    }

}
```

Goal: Get UserWCPModel and save ONLY data from that model without harming data populated by other applications (email, phone, fullname) while also completely avoiding reload of data from database.

First, a HttpPost Edit action:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(UserWCPModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            WrappedE result;
            repo.Update(model, out result);
            if (result.ErrorCode != ErrorCodes.Success)
            {
                /// Add error handling;
            }
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(model);
    }
```

As you can see, I only call Update method from repository, by passing a UserWCPModel.

Now here is repository method:

```
    public void Update(UserWCPModel model, out WrappedE result)
    {
        User user = new User();           
        user.UserId = model.UserId;        
        db.Users.Attach(user);
        user.LoadWCPModel(model);
        user.Modified = DateTime.UtcNow;
        SaveToDb(out result);
    }
```

1. I construct blank User object.
2. I assign it ID taken from model.
3. I attach it to DbSet Users.
4. I load data from UserWCPModel to User object.
5. I set modified time (not of importance).
6. I call db.SaveChanges() (that is what SaveToDb does).

GOAL accomplished!
No 2nd SELECT query.
No saving data that is not model related.
No calling of IsModified for every property.
No harm to previously entered data that is out of scope of model.

I tweaked it so badly that I have to share it here, and hope for some comments :D

Hope someone will find this useful :)

Comment: It works, but only because you are making DB and UI intentionally "inconsistent", so to speak, since you have *optional/nullable* columns in the database but *required* properties in the UI. Maybe you want or need that, but I would call this a very "special" architecture.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using this method for updating entities you need to be really careful; conciser what will happen if you try and update the same entity twice on the same context. (Spoiler: you will get an exception when you try to attach an entity which is already attached)

In addition i would recommend you add `.AsNoTracking()` (see [my blog post on AsNoTracking](http://blog.staticvoid.co.nz/2012/04/entity-framework-and-asnotracking.html)) to all queries so that you act on read-only entities up until you actually perform an update. This will also help avoid double attaching entities to your context.

I suppose this method seems to me like you are treading on dangerous ground unless you absolutely need to use this method for performance reasons. In my opinion you would be far better to get the entity from the db first and update the properties manually and save it. This will probably save you headaches in the long term.